# Understanding and intuition for the adjoint action of a Lie group on its Lie algebra

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We denote $G$ a Lie Group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its lie algebra. I would like to what the intuition behind these adjoint actions $\text{Ad}$ and $\text{ad}$ are. Could you please give a concrete example for me of how these look. I have heard that they can be thought of as first and second derivatives but I do not have a good example to see why this is the case.

Here is my understanding; perhaps it will help you to guide your answer.

---

Given a Lie group $G$, we may define an action of $G$ on itself which is infact an automorphism. Namely take any $g\in G$ and define the congugation $C_g:=R_{g^{-1}}\circ L_{g}$. The tangent map of $C_g$ at the identity is then $d_eG_g:T_e G\rightarrow T_{g^{-1}eg}G$. We identify $T_eG$ with the lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and we will denote the tangent map by $\text{Ad}(g):\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$.

How do we compute this map? $\text{Ad}(g)$ takes in tanget vectors/ elements of the lie algebra. So lets apply $\text{Ad}(g)(X)$. This is $d_e(R_{g^{-1}}\circ L_g)(X)$.
The chain rule gives $d_{L_{g}(e)}(R_{g^{-1}})\circ d_e(L_g)(X)=d_{g}(R_{g^{-1}})\circ d_e(L_g)(X)$. I don't see reduce this down further in full generality. Perhaps there is something like left and right multiplication are both linear maps and hence equal to their derivatives. But I don't think these maps are linear unless we have a matrix group. Even if this was true then there are many identifications hidden in the statement "equal to their derivative".

Using the various $\text{Ad}(g)$ we can define a map $\text{Ad}:G\rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$. I believe this is what is called the adjoint action of a Lie group. Where $g\in G$ acts on $X\in \mathfrak{g}$ by $g*X:=\text{Ad}(g)(X)$. This should be an action due the chain rule.

---

I would like an answer to this question to give some intuition about what the adjoint action does or tries to measure, along with an example to demonstrate this .